# Password for GUI not working but same password in command prompt is working

Tags: password

While installing Ubuntu 12.04 I choose the language and keyboard as English(UK).
I changed them to English(USA) later. After this I'm not able to login in GUI, whereas I'm able to login in command prompt. This is strange.

Someone kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Something makes difference, try type it somewhere else if you're typing really that password, To change password press CTRL + ALT + F1 > there you log-in and type "passwd" or passwd "username" and press enter, it will ask for new password